# Terraform script to deploy MySQL and PhpMyAdmin in docker containers as a services

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, terraform, phpmyadmin

I try to convert `docker-compose.yaml` deployment file to `Terraform` script.
The task is to run `MySQL` and `PhpMyAdmin` in separate docker containers and access the database from `PhpMyAdmin` UI in the browser.

The following `docker-compose.yaml` works fine. When I execute command `docker-compose up` it deploys both images and the database is accessible on URL `localhost:8080` in the `PhpMyAdmin` UI. Graphical UI does not request password from database. Database `edu` is directly accessible to the `myuser`.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mysql:
    image: arm64v8/mysql:8.0.33
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_DATABASE: edu

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - PMA_USER=aabor
      - PMA_PASSWORD=123
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
```

I created the `Terraform` deployment script that should show the same behavior (`main.tf`).

```
   terraform {
    required_providers {
        docker = {
        source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
        version = "~> 3.0.1"
        }
    }
    }

    provider "docker" {}

    resource "docker_image" "mysql" {
    name         = "arm64v8/mysql:8.0.33"
    keep_locally = true
    }

    resource "docker_image" "phpmyadmin" {
    name         = "arm64v8/phpmyadmin:5.2.1-fpm"
    keep_locally = true
    }

    resource "docker_service" "mysql" {
    name = "mysql"

    task_spec {
        container_spec {

        image    = docker_image.mysql.image_id
        hostname = "mysql"
        env = {
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = 123456
            MYSQL_PASSWORD      = 123
            MYSQL_USER          = "myuser"
            MYSQL_DATABASE      = "edu"
        }
        }
    }
    }
    resource "docker_service" "phpmyadmin" {
    name       = "phpmyadmin"
    depends_on = [docker_service.mysql]
    task_spec {
        container_spec {

        image    = docker_image.phpmyadmin.image_id
        hostname = "phpmyadmin"
        env = {
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = 123456
            MYSQL_PASSWORD      = 123
            MYSQL_USER          = "myuser"
            PMA_HOST            = "mysql"
            PMA_PORT            = 3306
        }
        }
    }
    endpoint_spec {
        mode = "vip"
        ports {
        name           = "phpmyadmin"
        protocol       = "tcp"
        target_port    = "80"
        published_port = "8080"
        publish_mode   = "host"
        }
    }
    }
```

To simplify things I removed all secrets and mounts from both `docker-compose` and `Terraform` examples.

Command `terraform apply` completes without mistakes. This script deploys both docker containers. `docker ps` and `docker service ls` show that containers are up and running, but `PhpMyAdmin` is not accessible from the `localhost:8080`.

How do I modify the `main.tf` script to deploy properly MySQL and PhpMyAdmin UI connected to database?